# Motorola edge 40: Audio stops when recording

Tags: audio, motorola

I upgraded from Samsung to this Motorola phone, and a problem I'm having is the audio stops when I record a video. Is there anyway to allow audio to play still?

Comment: What has the switch of phones got to do with it?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. By "*the audio stops when I record a video*", did you mean you're playing audio using a different app at the same time?

Comment: Yes, ymusic player @AndrewT.

Comment: This happens in all android devices